# How to set auto increment value for a database field in codeigniter?

Tags: database, codeigniter, auto-increment

I am new to the codeigniter framework and don't understand how to set the auto increment value for my database table.

I want to set the id field in my log table as auto increment. But set the starting "id" value as 123. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

As i understand you want to start your auto increment after the `123`. To start your auto increment after your own unique number do this in your mysql database:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 123;
```

take a look for more details on [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with Codeigniter framework. For auto-incrementing a table from a fixed number, please do the following.

```
ALTER TABLE 'table_name' AUTO_INCREMENT= 123;
```